# How to find which version of rust should be used with a given solana-program / solana-cli version

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli

Where does solana keep track of the latest version of rust that can be used with a given version of solana-program or solana-cli?

I've looked in this file before but the specific version number has since been removed and in general this doesn't seem like a very good way to track the latest version.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/ci/rust-version.sh

There must be some official place this is mentioned that I haven't found?

Comment: To me it seems it's the file expected to be used:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/28191#issuecomment-1281209482
```
We do actually define the supported rust versions (stable and nightly) for each branch of the repo in this file:
```

Comment: They don't keep it there any more. In the 1.15 releases there's no version number there anymore. It's an environment variable now. Also it seems like the kind of thing that it would be important for Solana labs to publicise since they're running a parallel version of rust and people really need to know which version to use since not all are valid.

Comment: +1. Just from that file it could be the https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/rust-toolchain.toml to use?

Comment: Perfect, that looks like the right answer if you want to respond with that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported stable Rust version could be found from within the file https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/rust-toolchain.toml

as the Rust toolchain configuration (https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/concepts/toolchains.html)

```
[toolchain]
channel = "1.67.1"
```

Per discussion at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/28191#issuecomment-1281209482 you can use the supported version by running the `./cargo` script in the repository's top level directory.